# How do Beats receive configuration changes from Beats Central Management (i.e REST)?

Tags: elastic-stack, elastic-beats

I am trying to find how the Beats Central Management console in Kibana deploys configuration changes to enrolled Beats.

I have searched the documentation of both Beats and Beats Central Management, but have seen no clear detail specifying how these changes are deployed. I know that when a Beat is enrolled it receives an "access token" for configuration polling, but does this mean that REST is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was confirmed by an Elastic team member that the changes are deployed through HTTP calls.